# Recursive directory rename with subfolder level control

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch-file, rename

**My Challenge:** Recursively renaming the 3rd subfolder `{subf3}` and beyond {subf4, 5, 6, ...} of a root path to keep only the first 4 characters of their original folder name.

> e:\ {rootf} \ {subf1} \ {subf2} **\ {subf3} \ {subf4} \ {subf5} \ ...**

See tree  which shows how the script should process subfolder renames with (**before**) and (**after**) it's processed.

Additionally, I need root folders marked with "x" as 1st character of root folder position "`\ {rootf}`" i.e. "`\xNew Folder\`" to be omitted (**skipped**), and not processed or renamed at all.

```
\long path1 (BEFORE)

├───long path1
│   └───long path
│       └───long path
│           └───long path
│               └───long path
│                   └───long path
│                       └───long path
│                           └───long path

\long path1 (AFTER)

├───long path1
│   └───long path
│       └───long path
│           └───long
│               └───long
│                   └───long
│                       └───long
│                           └───long

(SKIPPED)  \xNew folder , has "x" as 1st character)

├───xNew folder
│   └───New folder
│       └───New folder
│           └───New folder
│               └───New folder
```

Here is a PowerShell logic I've come up with but it is not working and giving me errors.

```
$rootFolder = "E:\"

# Define a function to recursively rename subfolders
function Rename-Subfolders($folder) {
    $subfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Directory | Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike 'x*' }

    foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders) {
        $originalName = $subfolder.Name

        # Rename only the 2nd subfolder and beyond
        if ($subfolder.Parent.Parent) {
            $newName = $originalName.Substring(0, 4)

            # Display the original and new names before renaming
            Write-Host "$($originalName) (BEFORE)"
            Write-Host "└───$($newName) (AFTER)"

            # Rename the subfolder
            Rename-Item -Path $subfolder.FullName -NewName $newName
        }

        # Recursively process subfolders
        Rename-Subfolders -folder $subfolder.FullName
    }
}

# Start renaming subfolders from the root folder
Rename-Subfolders -folder $rootFolder

Rename-Subfolders -folder $rootFolder -depth 0
```

Results in this error:

```
long path (BEFORE)
└───long (AFTER)
Rename-Item : Access to the path 'E:\long path1 (AFTER)\long path' is denied.
At E:\renametest.ps1:19 char:13
+             Rename-Item -Path $subfolder.FullName -NewName $newName
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (E:\long path1 (AFTER)\long path:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Comment: Hello, I downloaded and tried the majority of the tools on this [link](https://techcult.com/best-free-file-rename-software-for-windows/). I didn't find anything similar/"workable" on the superuser site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Recursive directory rename using depth and length control

With the recursive rename using `Rename-Item` you will want to start with the last folder first, rename it, and then step backwards from there renaming its parent folder until you reach the minimum file path depth.

This may give others ideas now to write something more optimized perhaps with less variables and some refactoring, but this seems to do exactly what you describe you need.

It does not rename the root level parent folder or the subsequent two subfolders beneath each. It also will omit root level folders with the character to omit as the value of the `$NotLike` variable.

### Control by folder depth and full path length (table list detail only)

```
$NotLike = "x";
$rootPath = "E:\";

$rootFolders = (Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPath -Directory | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "$NotLike*"}).FullName;

$rootFolders | ForEach-Object {
    $subFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Recurse -Directory;
    $dCnt = 0;
    $Output = @();
    $subFolders | ForEach-Object { 
        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Depth" -NotePropertyValue $dCnt;
        If ($_.Depth -gt 1) {$Output += $_};
        $dCnt++
        };
    $Output | Sort-Object @{E={$_.FullName.Length}} -Descending | Select  Depth, @{N="Length";E={$_.FullName.Length}}, FullName

    };
```

#### Output

```
Depth Length FullName                                                                                  
----- ------ --------                                                                                  
    6     90 E:\Long Path1\Long pathA\Long PathB\Long PathC\Long PathD\Long PathE\Long PathF\Long PathG
    5     79 E:\Long Path1\Long pathA\Long PathB\Long PathC\Long PathD\Long PathE\Long PathF           
    4     68 E:\Long Path1\Long pathA\Long PathB\Long PathC\Long PathD\Long PathE                      
    3     57 E:\Long Path1\Long pathA\Long PathB\Long PathC\Long PathD                                 
    2     46 E:\Long Path1\Long pathA\Long PathB\Long PathC
```

### PowerShell (The Rename Operations)

```
$NotLike = "x";
$rootPath = "E:\";

$rootFolders = (Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPath -Directory | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "$NotLike*"}).FullName;

$rootFolders | ForEach-Object {
    $subFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Recurse -Directory;
    $dCnt = 0;
    $Output  = @();
    $subFolders | ForEach-Object { 
        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Depth" -NotePropertyValue $dCnt;
        If ($_.Depth -gt 1) {$Output  += $_};
        $dCnt++
        };
    $Output | Sort-Object @{E={$_.FullName.Length}} -Descending | ForEach-Object { 
        If ($_."Depth" -gt 1) {$_ | Rename-Item -NewName $_.Name.Substring(0, 4) -Force}}
    };
```

#### Tree Before

```
E:\
├───Long Path1
│   └───Long pathA
│       └───Long PathB
│           └───Long PathC
│               └───Long PathD
│                   └───Long PathE
│                       └───Long PathF
│                           └───Long PathG
└───xLong Path1
    └───Long pathA
        └───Long PathB
            └───Long PathC
                └───Long PathD
                    └───Long PathE
                        └───Long PathF
                            └───Long PathG
```

#### Tree After

```
E:\
├───Long Path1
│   └───Long pathA
│       └───Long PathB
│           └───Long
│               └───Long
│                   └───Long
│                       └───Long
│                           └───Long
└───xLong Path1
    └───Long pathA
        └───Long PathB
            └───Long PathC
                └───Long PathD
                    └───Long PathE
                        └───Long PathF
                            └───Long PathG
```

## Supporting Resources

- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)
- [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.3)
- [About Comparison Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6)
- [About Assignment Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-6)
- [Add-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-7.3)
- [Sort-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.3)
- [Add a calculated property with Select-Object in PowerShell](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/)
- [Powershell script to list ,in reverse order, files recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49719503/powershell-script-to-list-in-reverse-order-files-recursively-similarly-to-thi)

Answer (score 1):

This script is exactly what I wanted and more.  The only future change I may make to it is removing the subfolders that have 1 character.  For now this is good enough, I don't have the time to dig into error handling, logging and other issues during move operation conflicts.

RENAME SCRIPT

```
$rootPath = "E:\";

$rootFolders = (Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPath -Directory | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "$NotLike*"}).FullName;

$rootFolders | ForEach-Object {
    $subFolders = (Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Recurse -Directory);
    $Output  = @();
    $lastskipped = 0
    $lastskippedct = 0;
    $subFolders | ForEach-Object {
        $dpth = $_.FullName.Split("\").Count -1;
        $childFolderCount = (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Directory).Count;

        if ($_.FullName -like "$lastSkipped*") {

            return;
        }; 

        $lastskipped = 0;
        $lastskippedct = 0;

        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Depth" -NotePropertyValue $dpth; 
        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "CFldrCT" -NotePropertyValue $childFolderCount;
        if ($dpth -ge 4 -and $childFolderCount -gt 1) {

            $lastskipped = $_.FullName;
            $lastskippedct++
            if ($lastSkippedct -eq 1) {
                $Output += $_;

            };
            return; 
        } elseif ($dpth -ge 4 -and $childFolderCount -le 1) {
            $Output += $_;
        };
        };

$Output | Sort-Object @{E={$_.Depth}} -Descending | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_.Name -ne $_.Name.Substring(0, 1)) { 
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name.Substring(0, 1)) -Force
    };
};
};
```

BEFORE

```
├───Beta
│   ├───expert expert exp
│   │   └───expert expert expert expert expert expert2
│   │       └───expert expert expert expert expert expert
│   │           └───expert expert expert expert expert expert
│   │               ├───fundamentals fundamentals
│   │               └───zero 2 hero zero 2 herozero 2 herozero 2 hero
│   ├───fundamentals fundamentals
│   │   └───fundamentals fundamentals4
│   │       └───fundamentals fundamentals
│   │           └───fundamentals fundamentals
│   │               └───fundamentals fundamentals
│   │                   └───fundamentals fundamentals
│   │                       ├───expert expert expert expert expert expert
│   │                       ├───fundamentals fundamentals
│   │                       └───zero 2 hero zero 2 herozero 2 herozero 2 hero
│   │                           ├───New folder2
│   │                           ├───New folder3
│   │                           └───New folder4
│   └───zero 2 hero zero 2 her
│       └───zero2herozero2herozero2herozero2hero2
│           └───zero2herozero2herozero2herozero2hero
│               └───zero2herozero2herozero2herozero2hero
│                   ├───fundamentals fundamentals
│                   │   └───fundamentals fundamentals
│                   │       ├───New folder
│                   │       ├───New folder2
│                   │       ├───New folder3
│                   │       └───New folder4
│                   └───zero2herozero2herozero2herozero2hero
```

AFTER

```
├───Beta
│   ├───expert expert exp
│   │   └───expert expert expert expert expert expert2
│   │       └───e
│   │           └───e
│   │               ├───fundamentals fundamentals
│   │               └───zero 2 hero zero 2 herozero 2 herozero 2 hero
│   ├───fundamentals fundamentals
│   │   └───fundamentals fundamentals4
│   │       └───f
│   │           └───f
│   │               └───f
│   │                   └───f
│   │                       ├───expert expert expert expert expert expert
│   │                       ├───fundamentals fundamentals
│   │                       └───zero 2 hero zero 2 herozero 2 herozero 2 hero
│   │                           ├───New folder2
│   │                           ├───New folder3
│   │                           └───New folder4
│   └───zero 2 hero zero 2 her
│       └───zero2herozero2herozero2herozero2hero2
│           └───z
│               └───z
│                   ├───fundamentals fundamentals
│                   │   └───fundamentals fundamentals
│                   │       ├───New folder
│                   │       ├───New folder2
│                   │       ├───New folder3
│                   │       └───New folder4
│                   └───zero2herozero2herozero2herozero2hero
```